# Typescript cannot find modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules, typescript-typings

A .ts file with imports I am migrating from a previous version that uses a typings file.

```
import util = require("util");
import Promise = require("bluebird");
import onoff = require("onoff");
import Gpio = onoff.Gpio;
```

and I have the @types for those imports

```
├── @types/bluebird@3.5.27
├── @types/node@12.0.10
├─┬ @types/onoff@3.2.1
│ └── @types/node@12.0.10 deduped
```

And I have a tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir":"./out/"
  }
}
```

But I get an error and I cannot figure out how to debug further

```
lib/GPIOPort.ts(5,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'util'.
lib/GPIOPort.ts(6,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'bluebird'.
lib/GPIOPort.ts(7,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'onoff'.
```

Comment: Can you share the path of your source file relative to the tsconfig? Are there any other tsconfig files that might be active?

Comment: The files are in the lib directory. lib/GPIOPort.ts the modules however are globally installed. Unless there is a global tsconfig there is nothing else in the folders. There was a typings.js file that i deleted doing the upgrade.

Comment: My hunch is that @types packages need to be locally installed